# Column span in nebula XViewer

Tags: grid, nebula, columnspan

I am using using nebula XViewer to display a data in grid format. I have an issue when i am trying to perform column span. Can any one help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You have to be a LOT more specific. For example, what is your issue?

Comment: I am displaying a data in a tree view and i want to create section header. For example if i am having 12 columns in my Xviewer then i will get 12 cells. My issue is i want to span 1st cell of 1st row in Xviewer,that is i want only one cell in first row. when i click on my section header(1st row) it should expand and child elements should visible.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you can define your custom Content Provider:

```
contentProvider = new CustomXViewerContentProvider();
```

where CustomXViewerContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider

```
public class CustomXViewerContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {
```

in this class you can @Override method **getChildren**, **getParent**, **hasChildren** depending on your data model.
With these methods you can create the parent and child hierarchy

Once the content provider has been created you assign it to the xviewer:

```
XViewer.setContentProvider (contentProvider );
```